# custom column IP:PORT Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, endpoint

can you help me add custom column in Kubernetes Dashboard DEPLOYMENT web interface, which looks like CLUSTER-IP : PORT
endpoints have this data.

how can i make this?

https://ibb.co/Sm2DSCF

https://ibb.co/6gh5xNK

i tryed a lot of tutorials, but not found web version, only terminal

Comment: Which web interface are you referring to?

Comment: hello! https://yourimageshare.com/ib/v9ACmP0Cnw